# Openresty/nginx ngx.say() starts download

Tags: nginx, openresty

When I use ngx.say() in Lua, to output something, it starts downloading in browser.
Try this url - http://162.241.200.114

I don't know what I'm supposed to do to fix this

Also how to check the domain name and subdomain for the request using Lua.

Comment: Please show your nginx.conf and the rest of the code. Without them, there is not much anyone can say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the default headers for openresty defines content-type as octet-stream.
changing header with 
    ngx.header['content-type'] = 'text/html' 
Fixed it